# Assigning alpha from scrollview delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uiscrollview, uilabel

I added two labels to my navigation bar and I'm trying to fade one out and fade another in, based off of the y position on the scrollview. When I log the alpha value it seems as if the values are correct. But way it looks when you run it is not right. The alpha of the topTitleLable goes from 1 to almost 0 then slowly fades in instead of out. Not sure how to debug this.

This is image of downward scroll with the label fading in when it should be fading out:

[image]

**tldr:** How do you change a labels alpha based off the scrollView position?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
static CGFloat startFade = 190;
static CGFloat endFade = 215;
CGFloat difference = endFade - startFade;

if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < startFade && self.navigationController.topTitleLabel.alpha != 1.0) {
    self.navigationController.topTitleLabel.alpha = 1.0;
    self.navigationController.bottomTitleLabel.alpha = 0.0;
} else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= startFade && scrollView.contentOffset.y <= endFade) {
    CGFloat scrollViewFraction = difference - (scrollView.contentOffset.y - startFade);
    CGFloat topLabelAlpha = scrollViewFraction/difference;
    CGFloat bottomLabelAlpha = 1 - topLabelAlpha;
    self.navigationController.topTitleLabel.alpha = topLabelAlpha;
    NSLog(@"%f VS. %f", topLabelAlpha, self.navigationController.topTitleLabel.alpha);

    self.navigationController.topTitleLabel.alpha = bottomLabelAlpha;
} else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > endFade && self.navigationController.topTitleLabel.alpha != 0.0) {
    self.navigationController.topTitleLabel.alpha = 0.0;
    self.navigationController.bottomTitleLabel.alpha = 1.0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to get at functionally, but I know it's sometimes tricky to make continuous changes based on a scroll offset.

What generally solves the problem for me is to realize that I need to write (and test) a function that maps y-offset to some real number output.  It's often helpful to sketch a graph of this function....

```
alpha |
      |
    1 |         /------
      |        /
      |       /
    0 |------/
      --------------------- y offset
             |   |
            190 215
```

This provides a good guide for something like this...

```
- (CGFloat)bottomLabelAlphaAtY:(CGFloat)y {
    if (y < 190) return 0;
    if (y >= 215) return 1;
    return (y-190) / (215-190);
}
```

**Before** we get all mixed up with scroll views, write a little test, like...

```
- (void)testBottomLabelAlphaFunction {
    for (int y=180; y<225; y+=0.5) {
        NSLog(@"y=%.2f f(y)=%.3f", y, [self bottomLabelAlphaAtY:y]);
    }
}
```

Read through the output and make sure it behaves as you expect.

A nice side-effect of factoring out the real-plane logic is that you can use compositions of already tested functions.  For example, still guessing about your exact functional goal, maybe you need something like...

```
- (CGFloat)topLabelAlphaAtY:(CGFloat)y {
    return 1 - [self bottomLabelAlphaAtY:y];
}
```

Another nice side effect is the simple clarity that you can get now in the delegate method...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    self.navigationController.topTitleLabel.alpha = [self topLabelAlphaAtY:y];
    self.navigationController.bottomTitleLabel.alpha = [self bottomLabelAlphaAtY:y];
}
```

Comment: @dahh Wow thank you so much! I ended up using a different method for the two labels so that fade in and out at different y values but the graph was hugely helpful.